# Display data from sqlite file using phonegap

Tags: sqlite, phonegap

I am new for developing apps using phone gap. I want to develop app for both ios and android. SO i thought to use phone gap. I want to display data from a predefined sqlite file into a list view. When I searched i found that sqlite file must be placed inside www folder. How to display data from here after that? I follwed this tutorial to develop my first app sing phone gap. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq2EDVJr_v8  Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install SQlite Plugin
2. Waiting for devideready event
3. Open your database (that you put in www folder)  using sqlite plugin:

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'your_database_name.db', location: 'default'});

After that you can execute transactions and queries:

```
db.transaction(
    function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('', [],
            // Success Callback
            function(transaction, result) {

            },
            // Error Callback
            function(transaction, error){
                alert(error.message);
            }
        );
    },
    // Error callback
    function(error){

    },
    // Success callback
    function(){

    }
);

db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], function(rs) {
    if(rs && rs.rows.length){
        for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++){
            // single row - rs.rows.item(i);
        }
    }
}, function(error) {
});
```

Here you can find very good examples:
https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: Hi...thank u so much...Can you please explain little more and suggest some links related to my requirement?

Comment: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/

https://gist.github.com/edwardtoday/2204864

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/03/04/phonegap-sample-diary-database-and-camera-support/

Comment: hi..I tried with this link. Here records are inserted using queries. Instead of this how can I display records from mydata.db file. I have tried and am not getting how to do this? Can you please help me?